# Table in table, fill column width

Tags: tables, pdftex

I'm trying to create a table inside a table. The second table doesn't use the full width of columns so there is a small space next to the vertical lines.

Currently it looks like this:
[image: table]

Is there some way to make the inner table use the full width of the outer column?

This my code:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
    \hline
    Byte 1 & Byte 2 \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}{ c | c  }
        \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c }
            7 & 6 & 5 & 4
        \end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c }
            3 & 2 & 1 & 0
        \end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Type & Id\\
    \end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}{ c }
        \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c }
            7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0
        \end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Data
    \end{tabular}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\MC\multicolumn
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | *{16}{c|} }\hline
\MC{8}{|c|}{Byte 1} & \MC{8}{c|}{Byte 2}\\\hline
7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0\\\hline
\MC{4}{|c|}{Type} & \MC{4}{c|}{Id} & \MC{8}{c|}{Data}\\\hline
\end{tabular}   

\end{document}
```

[image]